# Where is the __builtin__ module in CPython

Tags: python, cpython

I want to get the path and source code of the `__builtin__` module, where can I get it?

Comment: Do you mean the built-in C code for the ____builtin____ module or the Python code? If it's the latter, I am sorry it doesn't exist.

Comment: Taking into account that OP asked explicitly for **CPython**, it had to be clear that he doesn't need explanations about non-existense of python sources of the module.

Comment: @funktku, yes, you are correct. I see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Latest (trunk) C sources of `__builtin__` module: http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Python/bltinmodule.c?view=markup

Comment: That is great. Do you know which part of the module loading process handling builtin module specially?

Comment: @Thomson, I can't tell for granted, but perhaps no special code involved. Just a data structure (vulgar C `struct`) which defines the module and contains pointers to the functions we can see in the `bltinmodule.c`. Just as any other native module in C API. Then they probably just link the `bltinmodule.o` statically into `libpython.so`. Again — I don't know this for sure, just guesses. In any case, I'd did exactly like that.

Comment: @Thomson, so, it turns out that I was right. The module definitions go near the end of the file; regarding your question about loading of `__builtin__` module — this is simple too: the module gets loaded together with the interpreter; this is the way how static linking works. May I ask, what you are trying to do?

Comment: Nowadays, a current link to the source is: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c

Answer (score 2):

The `__builtin__` module is built-in, there is no Python source for it.  It's coded in C and included as part of the Python interpreter executable.

Comment: @Thomson I think it is in Python's source code. http://www.python.org/download/source/

Answer (score 2):

You can't. it is built-in to the interpreter.

```
>>> # os is from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'
>>> import os
>>> os
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> # PyQt4 is from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/__init__.pyc'
>>> import PyQt4
>>> PyQt4
<module 'PyQt4' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/__init__.pyc'>
>>> # __builtin__ is built-in
>>> import __builtin__
>>> __builtin__
<module '__builtin__' (built-in)>
```

In a program, you could use the `__file__` attribute, but built-in modules do not have it.

```
>>> os.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'
>>> PyQt4.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/__init__.pyc'
>>> __builtin__.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

Comment: Great, clearly explain my confusion "why `__builtin__  module has no attribute __file__`''. Thank you.